# Can I pass a generic type as a type parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an API client that can be sync or async, depending on the fetcher. Dramatically simplified, it's like this:

```js
function makeClient<F>({fetcher}: any): any {
  return {
    query: () => fetcher(`query`) as F<QueryResult>,
    toc: () => fetcher(`toc`) as F<TocResult>,
  }
}

makeClient<Promise>({fetcher: window.fetch}) // returns promises
makeClient<Identity>({fetcher: fetchSync}) // returns data
```

I'm running into `Type 'F' is not generic.` Is there a way to do this?

Here is the playground: https://tsplay.dev/N54OMw

Comment: Why would someone -1 this question without adding a comment? :-(

Comment: I suspect the concern is that you weren't very explicit about what you were trying to accomplish, but I agree a comment would have been helpful.  I take it you want the return type to depend on the type parameter, and have answered that question below.  If you meant something else, please clarify.  Thanks!

Comment: TS does not support higher kinded types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type parameters stand in for composed types, so as far as I know they can't be generic in the way it looks like you want.

You can, however, make your return type depend on a type argument using conditional types.  Here's a very explicit way to do it:

```js
interface QueryResult {}
interface TocResult {}
const fetchSync = () => ({})

// type alias we'll use to signal whether or not to wrap the result in a promise
type PromiseIndicator = 'promise_indicator'

// conditional type that wraps the second argument in a promise if, and only if, the first type argument is set to PromiseIndicator
type ConditionalPromise<T, F> = T extends PromiseIndicator ? Promise<F> : F

// F = string is just a default; it could be anything other than PromiseIndicator
function makeClient<F = string>({fetcher}: any) {
  return {
    query: () => fetcher(`query`) as ConditionalPromise<F,QueryResult>,
    toc: () => fetcher(`toc`) as ConditionalPromise<F,TocResult>,
  }
}

makeClient(fetchSync)
makeClient<PromiseIndicator>(fetchSync)
```

I suspect there's a cleverer way to do this in your actual code based on the actual type of `fetcher`, but for the snippet you've provided this should work.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=40&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFdoE8BKEDO6ANmMgN4C%20AUKJLIigCoD2CehJ51CzI%20pMCGAQALAMpYQCZAF5kACgCUsgHwLKiqlTBYADigAKUZgFtg%20CAEkQAE2AI4YZlFnIA5LuNmLAfVB2HJyg3LR19ZABhXjswYF44IiNTcwgAHkYAGmQAMTU5RmQIAA9IW3xkJO8rW3tHZ2QAfgqvFNTc5AAuHK0YdClY3mQTOABrCAiiYAhwNtd%20KFAAcxV5MkFhEWgKLrgQLGUyKmRkKCF0KBByI%20PkAEdMKCwupVVkddFoeQADe%20wv5Tg5SiNQGIASlVa2QyGGw7GIYBUGWuxycCGeyhkanemyg31R-2QgMi0WAoPBLQsbQyLDYBHhiOu1GoVGGYwmU3A8mxEikmlZ40m0zAqQhFmsATqUBW3MkCEUQA)

Comment: Thank you @sam256. I think that I'll be able to approach this differently using a mapped type to end up sync and async versions, but it might take a number of hours of experimentation first!